# Inserting into a BST

Tags: binary-search-tree

I want to create a visualization of a BST, but every example I find online stops after inserting only 7 or less values. Let's say I'm doing the following sequence:

insert(5),insert(7),insert(9),insert(8),insert(3),insert(2),insert(4),insert(6),insert(10).

Up until insert(6), I end up with:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/sFn8bSU.png]

My main question is: where do I go from here? Do I add on to my left-most leaf or do I add on to my "lowest" leaf?

Also: according to wikipedia the code for an insertion is:

```
void insert(Node* node, int value) {
    if (value < node->key) {
        if (node->leftChild == NULL)
            node->leftChild = new Node(value);
        else
            insert(node->leftChild, value);
    } else {
        if(node->rightChild == NULL)
            node->rightChild = new Node(value);
        else
            insert(node->rightChild, value);
    }
}
```

But according to this, once I'm at 8 and I get insert(3), it would add 3 to the left of 8, as it would compare 3 with the node 9, see that the less-than spot is already taken by 8, then rerun the insertion with 8 being the node compared to, and place the 3 as the left child of 8. But this would just create kind of a list.

Thanks.

Comment: It will be the left child of 4, indeed.

Comment: Do you need to allow repeated values?  If so, consider adding a counter to each node that keeps track of the number of occurrences of that value instead of having multiple `node`'s with that value in your tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seems to mislead you is that on every insert, *you must start from the root* (which, in your case, is 5). So, let's take the graph above and try to insert 3 following the algorithm you pasted:

```
3 < 5, we go left and we meet 3
3 == 3, we go right (here it's the same, the code above says "go right") and we meet 4
3 < 4, we go left. Since 4 has no left child, 3 becomes its left child.
```

Try to build your tree from zero using the algorithm above. Incidentally, you won't find many examples with n > 10 nodes, because they tend to be exceedingly long without any benefit for the reader.